# Java sum of 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sum

In my app I have 2 arrays

```
Integer[] array1= {1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 4, 10};
Integer[] array2= {200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1};
```

Now I want to multiply every element from the first array with every element from the second array and finally to sum, for example:

```
200x1 = 200; 100x2 = 200; 50x3 = 150; 20x8 = 160; 10x6 = 60; 5x4 = 20; 1x10 = 10;
```

and then to sum `200+200+150+160+60+20+10 = 800`

Comment: Cool. Go ahead.

Comment: Please do not ask us to write code for you :) Please do it by your own or look for a tutorial or search the internet for it.

Comment: @Stephen Reindl, Ok, I will have this in mind!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
total += array2[i] * array1[i];
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, I will mark as correct answer because you were first and vote up the @Dhruv Ramani's answer because also is correct. Thank you one more time!

Answer (score 3):

You can even use streams:

```
Integer[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 4, 10};
Integer[] array2 = {200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1};

public void test() {
    System.out.println(
            // Each index of the arrays.
            IntStream.range(0, Math.min(array1.length, array2.length))
            // Multiply the two array entries.
            .mapToLong(n -> array1[n] * array2[n])
            // Add them up.
            .sum());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer[] array1= {1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 4, 10};
Integer[] array2= {200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1};
int resultOfSum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length;i++){
    resultOfSum += array1[i]*array2[i];
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this :

```
int s=0;
for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
  s+=array1[i]*array2[i];
System.out.println(s);
```